# v-model in works in v-text-area but not in v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

If i change the component from `<v-autocomplete>` to `<v-text-field>` the binding works, but if i use  the autocomplete component, the `'queryString'` data always stays null. Am i missing something or could it be a bug?

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="queryString"
  outlined
  dense
  single-line
  solo-inverted
  append-icon="mdi-magnify"
  @keyup="search"
></v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: In autocomplete v-model is selected value from a list of items here in your code there is no items list so it always returns null which is your default value.

Comment: thank you very much. Archieved the desired result using search-input.sync